# Checking an item if it is in that list on python 3

Tags: python, list, search, element

I am looking for search method, which i can use in lists. Let me show you an example:

```
myList = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

myList.search(3) #returns true because there is 3 in list
myList.search(7) #returns false because there isn't 7 in list
```

is there a build-in function who can do this job? I mean i searched for google but i couldn't find it.

Thank you all.